# how to create tables using sql schemas

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, schema

how to create the schema,

AND USING SCHEMA HOW TO create tables under the schemas

Comment: Can you please explain your issue more clearly? Do you require syntax for creating a schema and create tables in that new schema?

Comment: I'm totally confused about the question >_<.  For creation of a table its just CREATE TABLE tableName(values_in_table)

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE SCHEMA RTFM AUTHORIZATION dbo
GO
CREATE TABLE RTFM.foo (bar int NOT NULL)
GO
GRANT SELECT ON ::RTFM TO MyRole
GO
```

[CREATE SCHEMA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189462(SQL.90).aspx) and [GRANT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187940(SQL.90).aspx)